# How do you add a homepage to your browser?

Tags: vb.net, browser

This is what i mean

When searching the internet when you type in the search bar what ever your homepage is it searches on your homepage.

for example you search dogs

this is what it does.

It does
https://www.google.com.ph/search?= + dogs

I would like to know how to do that except adding another textbox for it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your url in this format, for each more string you want to search +string it at the end. Navigating to that link will directly give you the page without having to set it as homepage. I guess thats what you are trying to do?

https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs+cats

https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs+cats+stringNew

Comment: Im now one step closer into fixing this problem. My next problem is now, when i search an actual website, it now searches as (homepage) + (website) or like this https://www.google.com/search?q=youtube.com

Comment: How are you accessing the search? Are u doing this in browser? If so which browser..post a screenshot of the dialogue box where you are searching that ..if possible

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you meant to say homepage, rather your search engine.
I'll include multiple search engines here and what to parse the query as.

#### Google

`https://www.google.com/search?q=%s`
%s = query, separated by "+"

#### DuckDuckGo

`https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=%s`
%s = query, separated by "+"

#### AOL (Who even uses this anymore anyways)

`https://search.aol.com/aol/search?q=%s`
%s = query, separated by "+"

#### Yandex

`https://www.yandex.com/search/?text=%s`
%s = query, separated by "%20" (URL-encoded space character)

#### WolframAlpha

`https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%s`
%s = query, separated by "+"

#### Bing

`https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s`
%s = query, separated by "+"

#### Quora

`https://www.quora.com/search?q=%s`
%s = query, separated by "+"

---

Honestly, most of them are separated by "+" anyways.

There are many different methods of encoding search strings (almost millions), which is why I won't list them all here. Essentially, just check for a space character and replace it with the "+" or the "%20"